# tooltip positioning based on window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a tooltip.
Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s6y4A/).

css code

```
a.tooltip:hover span{
 display:inline;
 position:absolute;
 border:1px solid #DCA;
 background:#FF4747;
 font-weight: bold;}
```

Now, if I resize the window and hover the content for the tooltip, the tooltip contents are not completely visible since the window has been resized to small.
In the fiddle, you can see this with the last element in the second row, if you resize the result window in the fiddle.

I want to position the tooltip in such a way that it is always visible even though the window size is changed.

I'm not familiar with window positioning properties. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try using Media Queries. http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: @shin. I wouldn't mind going for that. But browser compatibility is a problem since my project is mainly focusing on IE.

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s6y4A/3/)**

```
  a.tooltip span {
                  z-index:2;
                  display:none; 
                  padding:14px 20px;
                  width:inherit; 
                  line-height:16px; 
                  position: relative;
     }
    a.tooltip {
         position: relative;

    }
 a.tooltip:hover span{
       display:inline;
       position:absolute;
       border:1px solid #DCA;
       background:#FF4747;
       left: 0px;
       bottom: 15px;
       font-weight: bold;
}
```

To adjust the width in smaller screens, you can use the media queries:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
   a.tooltip:hover span{
           display:inline;
           position:absolute;
           border:1px solid #DCA;
           background:#FF4747;
           left: -30px;
           bottom: 18px;
           font-weight: bold;
    } 

}
```

**For very responsive positioning:**

```
$(".tooltip").hover(function() {
    var height = $(this).find('span').height();
    var top = $(this).offset().top;
    if(height > top){
     $(this).find('span').css("top","10").css("bottom","inherit");
    } else if(height < top) {
      $(this).find('span').css("bottom","10").css("top","inherit");
   }
 });
```

Add the above code in your JS

Comment: That's one way. Thanks for that. But it would be appropraite if the tooltip comes above since it is the last element. Instead of making scroll bar.

Comment: Make it bottom: 15px; instead of top:15px

Comment: It does the job. Partially. Now the same problem with the top element. Is there a way we can set all(left, right, top, bottom) ?

Comment: I have added some jquery to that. check http://jsbin.com/dabutico/1 For left and right, few more if conditions we need to add. But now currently its working for top and bottom

Comment: If you think it has solved your issue, mark it as answer i suppose

Comment: Definitely i would mark if its solves the issue. I tried the the jquery. But it is not quite working. When I run it in the IE, it's showing 'Done with errors'. And the error seems to be in the first character of the jquery.(This object does not support this property). Any thoughts to this ?

Comment: Oopps i missed $ at the beginning while copying from jsbin

Comment: Whether you had chance to check the jsbin link i sent

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54019/discussion-between-smashit-and-mohamedrias).

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 a.tooltip:hover span{
            display:inline;
                    position:absolute;
                        left:0px;
                        width:inherit; 
                    border:1px solid #DCA;
                    background:#FF4747;
                    font-weight: bold;
                     }
```